# Edmx file with Visual Studio 11 Beta .Net 4.5

Tags: visual-studio, edmx, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am having trouble creating a new edmx file using Visual Studio 2011 beta

- Target framework .Net 4.5
- Class library project

After adding an empty model I get the error below

> Error 6039: warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference
>   'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' matches 'System.Data.Entity,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089',
>   you may need to supply runtime policy \fjwflppr.0.cs(465,29) : error
>   CS1061: 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction' does not contain a
>   definition for 'IsComposableAttribute' and no extension method
>   'IsComposableAttribute' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Method not found: 'Boolean
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction.get_IsComposableAttribute()'.

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmfunction.iscomposableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) EdmFunction.IsComposableAttribute is only supported in .net 4.5 and the project by default references the dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Entity.dll` but the file Properties window in vs is showing `4.0.0.0`

I am confused about which version of System.Data.Entity.dll my project should reference to get the edmx designer to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was because the EF CTP uninstall didn't clean all files, it left a policy file which had binding to the old version "4.2.0.0", so VS will always look for that old version.

details here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665596/1261784