# how to use the include to load properties that are other models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using a lambda that was to return the ApplicationUsers regarding the search result. Include in you have the property I want to search the same time seek vehicles that is the driver:

I'm using the MySql Provider.

```
return View(context.Veiculos.Include(veiculo => veiculo.Motorista).ToList());
```

The Driver property returns null, but the property that references the table in this case is MotoristaID is always correct.

Veiculo Model:

```
public Guid MotoristaID { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser Motorista { get; set; }
```

ApplicationUser model:

```
 public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
```

This is one-to-many.

In the view, I note that the driver property is not charged, it generates a null reference error. I think it may have something wrong in mapping or something to do with Lazy Loading.

How to solve?

Comment: Have you tried using `Include("Motorista")` instead?

Comment: Also you don't need the `virtual` keyword with Eager Loading (which you are).

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino The error persist... acho que você é Brasileiro, o erro persiste hehe

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13314419/1241400

Comment: Even though we speak the same language. You shouldn't use it here. :P Just a friendly advice. Have you considered Lazy Loading?

Comment: @MatijaGrcic I Dont have system.data.entity on my "core" project... I'll tray to install and make a test again.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I do not know how right the lazy, but I tantei remove the virtual and not worked.

Comment: @MatijaGrcic You can put here the Url package for System.Data.Entity?

Comment: @LuizNegrini You just need to install EntityFramework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity%28v=vs.113%29.aspx and maybe read more about EF http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @MatijaGrcic the references are all correct...

Comment: If you do a `.ToString()` on the query (prior to `.ToList()` you should be able to see the SQL that is being produced. Does it appear to be joining on the Motorista table?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior http://pastie.org/10225928 please see the query

Comment: @LuizNegrini: Yeah, it's definitely not even trying to do eager loading. Are you sure that your foreign key relationships are configured correctly, so EF knows how your relationship is mapped in the database?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".